# Отправка запроса с node js на php

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express, axios

Я развернул локальный сервер php, и node js. Из браузера идет обращение на node js, а с него уже дальше нужно сделать post запрос на php.
Пока я работаю локально, post запрос с node js на php проходит удачно, все работает.
Сейчас я закинул php файлы на хостинг, и уже обращаясь по адресу хостинга получаю ошибку 403.
Подскажите как сделать запрос с локального node js сервера на удаленный php.

Код nodejs express:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: api.SERVER_URI,
  withCredentials: true
});

app.post('/init/', (request, response) => {
  let result;
  if (config.licKey.length === 16) {
    const userIdSync = machineIdSync({ original: true });
    const pathCheat = path.resolve("./").replace(/\\/g, "/");
    instance.post(`/user/initialize/`, {
      licKey: config.licKey,
      pathCheat: pathCheat,
      userIdSync: userIdSync
    }).then(function (res) {
      if (res.data.resultCode === 1) {
        store.set('user', res.data.user);
        let user = store.get('user');
        if (user.user_gamePath.length > 0) {
          result = { success: 1, message: user.user_gamePath };
        } else {
          result = { success: 0, message: 'Не указан путь к игре' };
        }
        response.json(result);
      } else {
        result = { success: 0, message: res.data.message };
      }
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
      result = { success: 0, message: 'Ошибка при обращении к серверу' };
      response.json(result);
    });
  } else {
    result = { success: 0, message: 'Неверные данные' };
    response.json(result);
  }
});
```

Ошибка:

```
    Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (D:\GitHub\wallHack\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (D:\GitHub\wallHack\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (D:\GitHub\wallHack\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:269:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:388:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1336:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  config: {
    url: '/user/initialize/',
    method: 'post',
    data: '',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.4',
      'Content-Length': 114
    },
    baseURL: 'http://testdeveloper.ru',
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    withCredentials: true,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    }
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'testdeveloper.ru',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 13,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: 'POST /user/initialize/ HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.21.4\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 114\r\n' +
      'Host: testdeveloper.ru\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 80,
      protocol: 'http:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/user/initialize/',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [Socket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 403,
      statusMessage: 'Forbidden',
      client: [Socket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'http://testdeveloper.ru/user/initialize/',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'testdeveloper.ru',
    protocol: 'http:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 114,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'http://testdeveloper.ru/user/initialize/',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 403,
    statusText: 'Forbidden',
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx-reuseport/1.21.1',
      date: 'Tue, 14 Sep 2021 15:18:19 GMT',
      'content-type': 'text/html',
      'content-length': '163',
      connection: 'close'
    },
    config: {
      url: '/user/initialize/',
      method: 'post',
      data: '',
      headers: [Object],
      baseURL: 'http://testdeveloper.ru',
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      withCredentials: true,
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      transitional: [Object]
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'POST /user/initialize/ HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.4\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 114\r\n' +
        'Host: testdeveloper.ru\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/user/initialize/',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'testdeveloper.ru',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: '<html>\r\n' +
      '<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n' +
      '<body>\r\n' +
      '<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n' +
      '<hr><center>nginx-reuseport/1.21.1</center>\r\n' +
      '</body>\r\n' +
      '</html>\r\n'
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите что значит ошибка 403 и хорошо подумайте

Comment: Я уже весь день с этой проблемой сижу, я понимаю что это ограничение доступа, но даже когда я просто в адресную строку вписываю ссылку, то мне выдается результат, и если я просто из браузера делаю обращение на php то так же все работает, ошибка только когда я это делаю из-под node js

Comment: выведите в лог значение `api.SERVER_URI`, просмотрите внимательно вывод ошибки запроса

Comment: добавил ошибку в вопрос.
 api.SERVER_URI хранит просто хост сервера, и меняется на dev или prod

Comment: ok. путём нехитрого тыканья палкой я выяснил, что ваш "внешний сервис" возвращает 403 тем, кого он считает "роботом". так что передайте ему заголовок "User-Agent", который его устроит, например, "Mozilla/5.0 (platform; rv:geckoversion) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion"

Comment: ВАУ, спасибо огромное, я сидел с этой проблемой около 9 часов, у меня уже 30 вкладок открыто в браузере, ваш ответ решил мою проблему

Comment: @AmelyFlovs пометьте ответ принятым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш "внешний сервис" возвращает 403 тем, кого он считает "роботом". Так что передайте ему заголовок "User-Agent", который его устроит.

К примеру, это можно сделать так:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: api.SERVER_URI,
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (platform; rv:geckoversion) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion',
  },
});
```